# Not showing images in browser - React

Tags: reactjs, image

I am trying to fetch the right image based on current state in my function, but for some reason everything works, just images are not available in browser and I have no idea why.

```
 const [firstImage, setFirstImage] = useState(1); //name of the image is 1.png
```

Returning an image - the path is of course correct:

```
<img src={`../assets/images/${firstImage}.png`}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to import your images, then add the images your state or an array of images. Then you can target or cycle through the images with your setImage index state value.

These links show why you cant just use pathnames:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

https://www.edwardbeazer.com/importing-images-with-react/

https://daveceddia.com/react-image-tag/

Heres an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-rgb-zxz36?file=/src/App.js:0-346

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// import img1 from "./img/img1.jpg"; // you can import them
// import img2 from "./img/img2.jpg";

export default function App() {
  const img1 = require(`./img/img1.jpg`); // or you can require them
  const img2 = require(`./img/img2.jpg`);
  const images = [img1, img2];
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={images[currentImage]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But I am using multiple images - do I have to import all of them ? That is such a waste of code lines, isnt it ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-rgb-zxz36?file=/src/App.js:0-346 Unfortunately, there is no way to get images in your component or file without importing them first.

Comment: @Eliot you can also require them 1 by 1 also, but its the same as just importing them at the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. But why in your example the useState is 0 ?